# Vuex (vuex-typex) suddenly throws unknown action type

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a hard time understanding my issue. I already experienced it in the past but cannot exactly remember how I got rid of it. Now again, I get a `[vuex] unknown action type: attributes/getAttributes` error out of the blue without even having touched any store related code. Potentially I re-added my npm packages/package-lock.json before it happened but that's just a guess as I don't know anything else that may have changed "fundamentally". All other store modules that are setup in the same way keep working without any visible difference in anything.

Console-logging the object `attributesDispatch` we see the contained function:

```
loadData() {
    console.log(attributesDispatch) // #1
    attributesDispatch.getAttributes() // #2
}
```

resulting in

## #1

```
{ getAttributes: ƒ }

getAttributes: ƒ (payload)
// contents:
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: index.js?fb46:86
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[5]
0: Closure (ModuleBuilderImpl.dispatch) {_this: ModuleBuilderImpl, namespacedKey: "attributes/getAttributes"}
1: Closure {ModuleBuilderImpl: ƒ}
2: Closure {__extends: ƒ, __assign: ƒ, vuex_1: Module, useRootNamespace: {…}, qualifyKey: ƒ, …}
3: Closure (./node_modules/vuex-typex/dist/index.js) {__webpack_require__: ƒ, exports: {…}, module: {…}, arguments: Arguments(3)}
4: Global {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}
```

## #2

```
[vuex] unknown action type: attributes/getAttributes
```

Any idea how I can proceed to tackle this issue? It may be related to `vuex-typex` - on the other hand I don't know why it should as it has been working before and still works for my other store modules.

Any help and hints are much appreciated!

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the rest of the relevant part of your store.js file or module, generally these types of issues have been to do with vuex namespacing for me.